# Bug with tag markdown in migrated question from Meta.SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, migration, markdown-rendering

[This question](/q/287278/335772), recently migrated from Meta.SO, has some joke tag markdown at the end to the non-existent tag [catharsis](/questions/tagged/catharsis).

The problem is, it still links to Stack Overflow (instead of on MSE, where it should). Could this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save some work, we don't re-render posts when they get migrated and just copy the already-existing rendered HTML over to the new site. The tag syntax is already of rare use (pretty much only on Meta sites) and is the only thing that breaks this process, so it doesn't make sense to complicate the migration process more by forcibly re-rendering every post that passes through it.

Instead, you can simply make a tiny or bogus edit to the post to force a re-render and update the link to the correct site.